# Capistrano deployment broken by new request for Capistrano-Harrow gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I thought my capistrano version was locked to 3.4.0, however it seems that it updated to 3.5.  I tried going back to 3.4, but I keep getting the following message when I try to deploy my project to server.

```
    DEBUG [72bb6fc3]    An error occurred while installing capistrano-harrow (0.3.2), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install capistrano-harrow -v '0.3.2'` succeeds before
bundling.
```

I'm not familiar with `capistrano-harrow`, but read a little and doesn't seem like something I need. I did add to my gemfile in hopes of getting the deployment to send but even though that seemed to install fine, it still errors out for deployment.  When I try executing `gem install capistrano-harrow -v '0.3.2'` - I get the following message and it doesn't install.

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError)
    bad response Not Found 404 (https://rubygems.global.ssl.fastly.net/quick/Marshal.4.8/capistrano-harrow-0.3.2.gemspec.rz)
```

Anyone know how I can either, opt out of harrow to try and get my deploy to work, or correct this issue to move forward? Thanks!

**Update**

I ran the following command to "opt-out", however, it still needs to build/install the gem I suppose which is currently the real issue.

`git config harrow.disabled true`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`capistrano-harrow`'s 0.3.2 version seems to be [yanked](https://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano-harrow/versions) from Rubygems. There's a hint in the `ERROR` message you've pasted: `Not Found 404` was received from the CDN.

If you're back on 3.4, the gem is not supposed to be in use but if you're running 3.5, please try to `bundle update capistrano`.

Comment: So I locked it to 3.5, just now and did bundle update capistrano.  Now my versions are capistrano 3.5.0 & capistrano-harrow 0.4.0.  However it looks for 0.3.2 version still when I try to do a deploy.

Comment: Is 0.3.2 still mentioned in your Gemfile.lock?

Comment: that was it! So I pushed it to the repo and deployed. Thanks for the help!

Comment: yanking a gem version breaks CI everywhere, however they seem to be doing it consistently. I think that's a very bad idea. Just saying.